# VirtualBox cannot correctly load Linux image on Windows 10

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtualbox

I am using the latest version of VirtualBox 6.1.16 r140961 (Qt5.6.2)on Windows 10 Pro v2004.

Loading an iso file (I tried MX Linux and Debian) and starting the VM instance will show me the splash screen to start the boot process, but it's not able to progress after the final message in the second image provided `mountpoint-cache hash table entries`

MX Linux boot screen:

[image: mxLinux boot screen]

VirtualBox hangs here:

[image: VirtualBox hangs here]

Comment: Where did you get the Linux image - are you sure it is a good image?  Make sure (BIOS) that hardware virtualization (VT-x) are enabled.  Try making any other virtual machine to ensure Virtual Box is working correctly.

Comment: You can have debian in WSL without a VM.

Comment: @harrymc I don't want/need this recommendation and this does not provide any troubleshooting help. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Is this 32bit windows or 32bit linux?  As @John asked... Is hardware virtualization (VT-x) enabled?

Comment: Yes it's the 64bit image latest stable from https://mxlinux.org/download-links/ and debian netinstall https://www.debian.org/CD/netinst/  Vt is enabled in the bios and in windows features

I'll try with default ubuntu download from here:https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop as well..

Comment: A standard iso from any of the main distributions + virtual box really should work out of the box - windows 10 seems to be the issue.

Comment: Everything is 64bit!

Answer (score 0):

I had an existing VM that was failing to boot at the same point. It happened after I had upgraded to VirtualBox 6.1. When I downgraded to 6.0.12 it still didn't work - but it did give me a more informative error:

`Call to WHvSetupPartition failed: ERROR_SUCCESS (Last=0xc000000d/87) (VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED).`

This points to an issue with the widespread conflict between VirtualBox and Windows Hyper-V. The resolution involves eliminating everything that could use Hyper-V in Windows, as described [here](https://technology.amis.nl/2019/12/03/resolving-issue-oracle-virtual-box-6-0-14-and-windows-10-call-to-whvsetuppartition-failed-verr_nem_vm_create_failed/). I found that I could boot to the Ubuntu 20.10 Live CD by just disabling 'Virtual Machine Platform' feature and leaving the WSL enabled (but must run version 1 to avoid conflict). This was a newly created VM with 4 processors.

Unfortunately, my existing VM still wouldn't boot and was now stuck at the point where it brings up the additional processors. I eventually got it to boot by changing the settings to use a single processor. Obviously that isn't ideal and the performance is substantially worse, so if anybody figures out a better solution please let me know.

**Update 2 days later:**
Once I had the old VM booting again I tried changing it back to using 4 processors. It successfully booted but performance still suffers. For comparison, I created a new VM with the same configuration (8GB mem, 4 CPU) and it requires about 1/6th the CPU load to run. So it appears (in my case) there is a performance drag associated with the older VMs running on the latest versions of Windows and VirtualBox, but if a new VM is created (where virtualization is disabled as noted above) then the performance issue doesn't seem to be present.

Comment: Just upgrading Virtualbox 7 helped in fixing the issue. So, this answer of `Windows update breaking Virtualbox` seems to be the real issue which was later resolved by VirtualBox developers.